# JTable cell returning null 

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using `JTextField` inside `JTable` cells; I use a `TabelModel` which has the dynamic data of the `JTable`. Now, when I click a button, I am reading a cell value.
Problem is the cell which has the present focus doesn't return the updated value. For example, consider this program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class MyTable extends JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{
            {"some"}, {"any"}, {"even"}, {"text"}, {"and"}, {""}},
        new Object[]{"Column 1"});

    public MyTable() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTable table = new JTable(tmodel);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyRenderer());
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        JButton jb = new JButton("click me"); //button to display last cell data
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, table.getModel().getValueAt(5, 0));
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jb);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new MyTable().setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JTextField editor = new JTextField();
        if (value != null) {
            editor.setText(value.toString());
        }
        return editor;
    }
}
```

Here I am leaving the last field empty. When I read it by

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(5, 0)
```

I get `null`. Now I change the value at 5,0, and again click the button, but now again I get `null`. Now surprisingly, I edit some other cell, again click button; now I get the correct data at cell 5,0! Why is this? Is this a bug? I tried several possibilities!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (e.g. should include explicit imports) 2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: check if `getValueAt(1, 0)` returns `any`, maybe the problem is with your indexes?

Comment: @h4b0 no no, I checked it multiple times. The cell which has focus returns the old value not the updated one.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your problem, your example works perfectly for me. It always correctly returns the value contained in the cell that is requested in getValueAt(int, int)

Comment: As ymene says pressing "enter" key solves the issue.
but asking user to press enter for each cell edit is not a solution.
anyone know how to commit it with code

Comment: you are doing something wrong in the code you are _not_ showing, or the other way round: the code you are showing is unrelated to the description of whatever problem you perceive :-) So yes, it's a bug - in _your_ code or in _your_ expectation. Show an SSCCE, then we might be able to help you finding that bug.

Comment: @kleopatra The real code is in a secure client Virtual machine.
The Example is perfect in depicting my problem. Maybe running my code can make you more clear on it.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incorporating @kleopatra's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7267729/230513) and @mKorble's helpful [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875199/230513), here are a few additional ideas based on your example. Note in particular the use of `setDefaultButton()` and [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) in conjunction with [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9874664/230513 */
public class MyTable extends JFrame {

    private static final String show = "Show";
    private DefaultTableModel tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][]{
            {"edit"}, {"any"}, {"cell"}, {"text"}, {"and"}, {"edit me"}},
        new Object[]{
            "Column 1"});
    private JTable table = new JTable(tmodel);
    private Action showAction = new ShowAction(show);
    private JButton jb = new JButton(showAction);

    public MyTable() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);
        KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(enter, show);
        table.getActionMap().put(show, showAction);
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(jb);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jb);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }

    private class ShowAction extends AbstractAction {

        private ShowAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (table.isEditing()) {
                table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
            }
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (row > -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    MyTable.this, table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyTable().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: THAT is an AWESOME solution...it's working perfectly 100% as I wanted.
Thanks everyone :)

Comment: polite cough ... the example is a bit convoluted with twirks that are neither needed nor recommended. a) All that's needed for the OPs example to work (now that I understood the problem, at last :-) is setting the terminateEdit client property b) the enter binding overwrites the table's own enter (which terminates the edit implicitly) c) never call a button's click if you don't really need it (instead, wire the actions) d) the safeguarding aginst not-yet committed edits feels upside down: should be done in show instead of enter

Comment: @kleopatra: Right on all counts; thanks. I plead careless cloning :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are several points to consider within your example:

First you should have a look in [Java - Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to learn about the concept of Renderer and Editor within JTables, because you kinda mix things up here. Within your Renderer you use a JTextField which doesn't make sense, because this object is just used to present the data within your tableModel. Normally a JLabel is used for presenting, since you wont ever edit a value within a Renderer.

Moreover your example (eventhough I haven't tried it yet) should work, since a JTable already has a DefaultEditor. Maybe you just forgot to commit the value with pressing enter before you clicked the button to check which value is in?

I really can just recommend for reading [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and search for some examples on how this is handled normally. You should find a lot of working examples.

Comment: The rendering is just a quick example of my real project. No prob with that.
You are right. pressing enter commits the change, but how to do it via code?
I did search a lot of examples. JTable & rendering & editing is not the issue. Getting the value is.

Comment: Your example doesnt seem to fullfil your usecase. What is it exactly you want your example to do? While you are editing the value in your cell, the data isn't saved in your TableModel, hence you can't ask the model for the current value, unless you commit( with pressing enter, or changing focus) the value. Do you need the value already while editing the cell?

Comment: @ymene ya i want the current value by committing, it's possible.I was not able to work it out by changing focus (actually button should take the focus when i click it rit?). i need the value when button is clicked after editing the cell.  terminateEditOnFocusLost is the solution :)

Answer (score 5):

I think that every type of Arrays start with 0 (zero), then output to the JoptionPane is correct (return empty String), little bit modified your original code, added most important Swing rulles

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyTable extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultTableModel tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{
                {"some"}, {"any"}, {"even"}, {"text"}, {"and"}, {"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},
            new Object[]{"Column 1"});

    public MyTable() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTable table = new JTable(tmodel);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton jb = new JButton("click me"); //button to display last cell data
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table.getModel().getValueAt(5, 0));
            }
        });
        add(jb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {//added initial thread

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ashok Raj be sure desing is about success, most important for compound JComponents, I leaving answering Renderer/Editor issue, because (@ymene) touched that issues, by answering your question

Comment: I agree with you, but the above picture is just an quick little example, not my actual application. I can do a workaround but I really wanted to know to fix this issue

Comment: @Ashok Raj not clear what do you fix, 1) JTable, 2) JTable with Renderer, 3) JTable with Editor,  4) JTable with Renderer and Editor too,

Comment: problem is when i edit a cell, it's data is not immediately retrievable as long as the cell has focus. all the Rendered & editor & Jtable are fine. no issues with them

Comment: @Ashok Raj ahaaaaaaaaa :-) , you are right, you have to call `stopCellEditing`, better could be reading answers by ([@kleopatra](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A203657+stopCellEditing)) or the same by ([@camickr](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A131872+stopCellEditing)), maybe there are another questions and answers, but I linked `TOP two answerers` on this forum

Comment: @trashgod thank you are right, simple and clear, but I'm not still sure if OP required to call `stopCellEditing` from `JButton` ??? directly, really don't know, not sure about, maybe :-)

Comment: just can agree with you mKorbel, but from what I understood so far, trashgods link is really what the OP is looking for. First I guessed he wanted to go for some live validation.

Comment: @trashgod please ignore my last idiotic comment, JButton's click take Focus by default, sorry my bad ..... errrgggt

Comment: @mKorbel: I typically do both; I use `terminateEditOnFocusLost`, as well as `stopCellEditing()` in my enter/solve `Action`.

Comment: @ymene for simple editor without InputMask works as we expecting, otherwise InputMask helt Focus until value isn't inputed correctly, but this issue could be about cancelCellEditing (maybe) too :-)

Comment: @mKorbel thanx a lot... terminateEditOnFocusLost is working good.
stopCellEditing won't help as it stops further changes in the table.
yet got a problem terminateEditOnFocusLost not working for the first time the app is run. any suggestions?

Comment: @AshokRaj: The credit goes to @kleopatra; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898379/230513).