# Java: break focus cycle in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

In my JTable, I want to edit all relevant cells like in Excel.

I implemented that ENTER stops editing the cell and transfers focus to the next cell. However, when I hit ENTER in the last cell, the focus cycle makes me jump to the fist cell. But I want to continue outside the table and set focus to a JButton.

How can I break this cycle?

Comment: Of course, I want to (only) hit ENTER to break the cycle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable` is *not* a spreadsheet, but [`setCellSelectionEnabled()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29) should allow you to proceed. Use `setDefaultButton()` as required, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898379/230513).

Addendum: In addition to `setDefaultButton()`, you can evoke any desired action in your custom `Action`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095442/230513).

Comment: Thanks. In your example, hitting ENTER always shows the dialog. However, I want to go to the next cell with ENTER. If it is the last one, I want to go to the JButton outside.

Comment: I don't understand; if the button is the default button, you don't _have_ to change focus. You can evoke any desired navigation action in your custom `Action`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9095442/230513).

Comment: Oh, using a custom Action is the missing part for my table! Thanks!