# When i navigate to some field using tab and enter some text text getting disappeared?

Tags: java, swing

I have a table of forms which accepts first name, last name etc. When I navigate through using the tab key and enter some text in first name, all of the text disappears and that row gets selected. I have tried almost all techniques.

Is there any way we can avoid that using coding?
If I use the mouse then it wont give that error.

Comment: And the related codes for this description is ...

Comment: Sounds like you've not overrriden setValueAt of the table model...assuming I've interrupted the question correctly...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"interrupted the question correctly."* Sloppy socks?  ITYM *"**interpreted** the question correctly."* ;)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Heat stroke...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an otherwise correct use of `JTable`, you may need to terminate the edit when focus is lost, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826753/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7267729/230513):

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);
```